# Can't use method agian

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble with looping my program so that it will continue until the user exits.

After the user chooses an option it will display the menu again from the while stmt I put but it wont go into the other methods again, it just keeps displaying the menu again. I think my problem is that the choice isn't "resetting" and the program already thinks that the user has input????

Thanks in advance for the help!  (Sorry I put the whole program in here I wasn't sure what was needed and what wasn't to solve this problem).

```
 /*This program simulates a simple ATM machine.
 User can withdraw and deposit money by entering correct acct number and password.*/

import java.util.*;

public class ATM {

public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in); 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String acctNum, pwd, verifyID;
    int choice, attempts=0;
    double acctBal, depositAmount, withdrawAmount;

    System.out.println( "Enter account number: ");
    acctNum=kbd.next();
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    pwd=kbd.next();

    verifyID=checkID(acctNum, pwd); 
    //calls checkID method and returns result to verify

    while(verifyID.equals("error") && attempts<=3) 
        //checkID returns "error" and the attempts are less than or equal to 3.
    {
        attempts++;
        System.out.println("Entered the incorrect account information please try again.\n");
        //verifyID=checkID(acctNum, pwd);

        if (attempts==4) //If Maximum attempts reached display message, then exit. 
        {
            System.out.print("Maxium attemps reached. Your session has ended.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Re-enter password: ");
            pwd=kbd.next();
            //verifyID=checkID(acctNum, pwd);
        }
    }
    acctBal=Double.parseDouble(verifyID); 
    //Changing the string from checkID method to double *(acct balance is returned)

    choice=menu();//Calls menu() method.

    switch (choice)
    {
    case(1)://user enters balance option.
        displayBalance(acctBal); //Call method displayBalance.
    break;
    case(2)://User enters deposit option.
        System.out.println("Enter deposit amount: ");
        depositAmount=kbd.nextDouble();
        acctBal=deposit(acctBal,depositAmount);//call method deposit().
        System.out.printf("Your new current balance is:$ %.2f\n", acctBal); //Print new acctBal to screen.
    break;      
    case (3)://User enters withdraw option.
        System.out.println("Enter amout to withdraw: ");
        withdrawAmount=kbd.nextDouble();
        acctBal=withdraw(acctBal, withdrawAmount);//call method withdraw().
        System.out.printf("Your new current balance is:$ %.2f\n", acctBal); //Print new acctBal to screen.
    break;
    case(4)://User enters log-out
        System.out.println("You have been logged out.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (choice==1 || choice==2 ||choice==3)
    {
        choice=menu();
    }       
}

public static void displayBalance(double acctBal)
{    
    System.out.printf("Your current balance is :$ %.2f\n", acctBal); //Displays current balance.
}

/*The checkID method determines if acctNum is a valid account number
and pwd is the correct password for the account.  If the account information
is valid, the method returns the current account balance, as a string.
If the account information is invalid, the method returns the string "error".*/

public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd)
{
    String result = "error";

    /* Strings a, b, and c contain the valid account numbers and passwords.
    For each string, the account number is listed first, followed by
    a space, followed by the password for the account, followed by a space,
    followed by the current balance.*/

    String a = "44567-5 mypassword 520.36";
    String b = "1234567-6 anotherpassword 48.20";
    String c = "4321-0 betterpassword 96.74";

    if(acctNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) && 
            pwd.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1, a.lastIndexOf(" "))))
    {
        result=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") +1);
    }
    else if (acctNum.equals(b.substring(0, b.indexOf(" "))) && 
            pwd.equals(b.substring(b.indexOf(" ")+1, b.lastIndexOf(" "))))
    {
        result=b.substring(b.lastIndexOf(" ") +1);
    }
    else if (acctNum.equals(c.substring(0, c.indexOf(" "))) && 
            pwd.equals(c.substring(c.indexOf(" ")+1, c.lastIndexOf(" "))))
    {
        result=c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" ") +1);
    }
    return result;

    // insert code here to determine if acctNum is a valid account number
    // and pwd is the correct password for the account.
}

public static double deposit(double acctBal, double depositAmount)
{   
    return acctBal=acctBal + depositAmount;
}
public static double withdraw(double acctBal, double withdrawAmount)
{
    if (acctBal<=withdrawAmount)
    {
        System.out.println("Insuffienct funds.");
        return acctBal;
    }
    else
    {
        return acctBal-withdrawAmount;
    }   
}

public static int menu()
{
    int input=0; 
    while (input>=0 || input<=5) //check side
        //Checking input from user is between 1-4.
    {
        System.out.println("\nMain Menu\n1. Display Balance\n\n2. Deposit\n\n"
                + "3. Withdraw\n\n4. Log Out\n\n(Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4):");
        input=kbd.nextInt();

        if (input<=0 ||input>=5)
            //If input is not between 1-4 print error.
        {
            System.out.println("Invaid input.");
        }
        else 
        {
            return input; //Calls whichever method the user selected. 
        }   
    }
    return input; //Calls whichever method the user selected. 
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please point us to the while loop that is troubling you?

Comment: `input>=0 || input<=5` is always true. Use `input>=0 && input<=5` to use the logical **and**.

Comment: @Tom, I rescind my earlier comment about your comment being the correct answer.  It should be `input <= 0 || input >= 5`.  No need to change the `||` to `&&`, because Harbinger wants the loop to keep repeating while the input is INVALID, not while it's VALID.

Comment: @DavidWallace The `while` loop could also be `while(true)`, without doing harm :D.

Comment: @Tom That's true.  I'm a fan of `for(;;)` myself, but whenever I post an answer with `for(;;)` in it, I get downvoted.  It just seems to be one of those things that some people don't like.

Comment: @DavidWallace I prefer `while(true)`, because in my opinion `for` should be reserved for counting loops only. But this is just my coding style and not a rule :D.

Comment: Sorry @KickButtowski I'm a noobie, and learning.  I'll make sure in future posts to put more informative information. Thank you pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

(1) You've made a simple typo.  The line

```
 while (input>=0 || input<=5)
```

should say

```
while (input <= 0 || input >= 5)
```

because you want the loop to keep running while the value of `input` is invalid.

(2) This part

```
while (choice==1 || choice==2 ||choice==3)
{
    choice=menu();
}
```

is entirely wrong, because you'll end up in a loop of gathering input and not acting on it.  You need your big `switch/case` statement to be inside this loop, not outside.

Comment: did you mean && instead of ||?

Comment: No, I absolutely did not.  @KickButtowski.

Comment: I assume that the second (and bigger) problem is here: `while (choice==1 || choice==2 ||choice==3) { choice=menu(); }`. If I'm wrong or if you update your answer, I'll definitely remove that downvote. (edit: that downvote was nonsense, but please consider updating your answer:)).

Comment: by the way, in her code, she said between 1 and 4 but she includes zero and five too?

Comment: @Tom - since you spotted this, not me, I've CW'ed this post.

Comment: @DavidWallace That doesn't matter (to me) who spotted which error as long as the question will be solved :).

Comment: Thank you @DavidWallace! That makes a lot of sense. Since I need the program to keep running while they were inputting the correct info. And now I know why it was stuck in a loop! Thank you! I was able to fix my issue with your explaination and now it's running correctly!

Comment: @HarbingerShiny Happy to help.  Good luck with your ongoing learning.